# How do I keep only one item open in a jQuery accordion with slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slidetoggle, jquery-ui-accordion

I managed to create a working jQuery accordion for a WordPress site. Now I'm wondering how to make sure only one block is open? Meaning when I toggle one item, the other two collapse automatically.

Any idea how to do this?

In addition, the code probably can be streamlined, but I'm not really sure how. It seems pretty repetitive:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".accordion-toggle-1", function() {
    jQuery(".row:nth-child(2)").nextUntil(".row:nth-child(12)").slideToggle();
    jQuery(".accordion-icon-1 h1").fadeOut(function () {
        jQuery(".accordion-icon-1 h1").text((jQuery(".accordion-icon-1 h1").text() == '+') ? '-' : '+').fadeIn();
    });
});
jQuery(document).on("click", ".accordion-toggle-2", function() {
    jQuery(".row:nth-child(13)").nextUntil(".row:nth-child(20)").slideToggle();
    jQuery(".accordion-icon-2 h1").fadeOut(function () {
        jQuery(".accordion-icon-2 h1").text((jQuery(".accordion-icon-2 h1").text() == '+') ? '-' : '+').fadeIn();
    });
});
jQuery(document).on("click", ".accordion-toggle-3", function() {
    jQuery(".row:nth-child(21)").nextUntil(".row:nth-child(25)").slideToggle();
    jQuery(".accordion-icon-3 h1").fadeOut(function () {
        jQuery(".accordion-icon-3 h1").text((jQuery(".accordion-icon-3 h1").text() == '+') ? '-' : '+').fadeIn();
    });
});

function starttoggle() {
    jQuery(".row:nth-child(2)").nextUntil(".row:nth-child(12)").slideToggle();
    jQuery(".row:nth-child(13)").nextUntil(".row:nth-child(20)").slideToggle();
    jQuery(".row:nth-child(21)").nextUntil(".row:nth-child(25)").slideToggle();
}
setTimeout(starttoggle, 1400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at examples provided here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

See heading "Accordion Example".